# Merge two conditions in regex

Tags: java, regex, salesforce

I have a free text field which can contain five words

Allowed pattern for each word is [\w+=,.@-]+

I want to add character length from 1 to 64 characters

for this I created 2 regex and using `'AND'` condition but I want to create only one regex
How can I do it

```
a) "[\\w+=,.@-]\\s{0,1}){1,5}"
b) "\\b\\w{1,64}\\b"
```

Input String

Acceptable -

`Test1`

`Test2`

`Test3`

`Test4`

`Test5`

Acceptable - `Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5`

Unacceptable - `Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4 Test55555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555`

I tried this one - `(^([\w\.\+\@\,]{1,64}){1}$)|(^([\w\.\+\@\,]{1,64}\s+){1,5}\s{0,1}$)`

But the above required an space at the end of last word, if anyone can help with the above one so that it does not require space at end then that will fix my problem

Comment: Is the length 1-64 for each word, or for the whole field?

Comment: Please add your input string and the result which you are expecting. It becomes very difficult to understand the requirement without that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text field can contain 5 words, and the maximum number of characters in total is 1 to 64, you can use a positive lookahead anchored to the start of the string.

Then you can match 1+ word characters and repeat 1-4 times matching a space and 1+ word character to prevent having to end the string with a space.

```
^(?=[\w+=,.@ -]{1,64}$)(?:\w+(?: \w+){0,4})$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is

  - `[\w+=,.@ -]{1,64}$` Match any of the listed 1-64 times an assert end of string
- `)` Close lookahead
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
  - `(?: \w+){0,4}` Repeat 0-4 times matching a space and 1+ word chars
- `)` close non capture group
- `$` Assert end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NBeFpZ/1)

In Java with double escaped backslashes:

```
String regex = "^(?=[\\w+=,.@ -]{1,64}$)(?:\\w+(?: \\w+){0,4})$";
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!
Just one question how can I make this work if the words can be separated by a space or new line?

Comment: @C0DEPirate Instead of matching a space, you could use `\s` to match a whitspace char which could also match a newline `^(?=[\w+=,.@\s-]{1,64}$)(?:\w+(?:\s\w+){0,4})$` See https://regex101.com/r/bXo8b9/1

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out my use case is words can be separated by a space or new line   and each word cannot be greater than 64 character and not more than 5 words 

Modified your regex to ^(?:\b[\w+=,.@-]{1,64}\b\s*){1,5}$ and it is working

Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 1):

Please have a try of the following pattern:

`^(?:\\b[\\w+=,.@-]{1,64}\\b\\s{0,1}){1,5}$`

[Regex101 - Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6L0rfN/1)

Comment: Thank you very much!! Just one question how can I make this work if the words can be separated by a space or new line?

Comment: Thanks Quinn, 

I was able to solve my issue with ^(?:\b[\w+=,.@-]{1,64}\b\s*){1,5}$

yours was also a working solution but I can only mark one correct answer !!! :)